# traduki al lingvo / traduki en lingvon

Tags: word-choice

En la Fundamento oni nur trovas `traduki en lingvon`. Oni tiam uzis `traduki al` por klarigi, kiu ricevis la tradukon.

Tamen, ekde 1990 pli malpli, en Tekstaro oni trovas pli kaj pli ofte la strukturon `traduki al lingvo`, kie `al` enkondukas la lingvon kaj ne plu la ricevanton/profitanton (oni verŝajne uzus `por` por tio).

Ebla klarigo [aperas en PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/al.html#i-jih):

> Iafoje oni montras per al rezulton de transformado aŭ ŝanĝado: Li disrompis ĝin al mil pecoj. Normale oni uzas en + N-finaĵon.

Ĉu `traduki al lingvo`, malgraŭ ĝia ofteco, estas malĝusta aŭ evitinda strukturo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mi pensas ke jes, la rekcio "traduki al lingvo" estas evitinda.

Ĉar Zamenhof mem uzis "en + -n" kaj ankaŭ multaj aliaj, oni povas konsideri, ke tiu rekcio estas la kutima. Ĉiuj aliaj povas kaŭzi, ke la leganto aŭ aŭskultanto ne tuj komprenos la mesaĝon.

Answer (score 1):

La prefero de 'en' + '-n' ne estas hazarda, ĉar ĝi korespondus la 'ventrosenton' de la uzantoj en kies lingvo oni uzas 'en' (+ akuzativo, se ĝi ekzistas). Al tiuj lingvoj apartenas tiuj bazaj kies lingvouzo Esperanto heredas: 'übersetzen **ins** Polnische' (de), 'translate **into** Polish' (en), ktp. Kelkaj latinidaj lingvoj certe uzas '*al*', kiel ekz. la Hispana. Sed mi konsentas, ankaŭ, ke la 'en'-formo estu preferinda.